# Inside out issue

Tags: mesh

I am trying to import a Fbx file that is created and exported in VSticther (Browzwear).

I use blender for a quick set up of the model, but when i try to import the model, the inside becomes inverted.... You know the deal. If I import the model, without using blender first, nothing gets inverted, but with the use of the blender export, the problems occur...

I have tried both flip, recalculate inside/outside. But nothing solves the issue... Some certain parts though can flip? If choose some of the mesh,  by using the "select box", i can use the flip functions, but this becomes very messy... When i try Using "A" and select all, nothing happens? By any change anyone who has tried this before and can help me out? See pics.

[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]
[image: Pic 3]
[image: Pic 4]
[image: Pic 5]
[image: Pic 6]
[image: Pic 7]

Comment: What happens with other files formats? Also does it have volume?

Comment: maybe check in the Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry > Clear Custom Split Normals?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I figured out a way to solve it. 

@moonboots tried that, but it did not do anything. 

The way I solved it, was to duplicated the mesh of the inside, then flip it, so at the inside, there exist both an "inside" and "outside" layer.